# Finding Tuple in list with three items matched

Tags: c#, string, indexing, tuples, wildcard

I need to get the index of a `Tuple<string,string,string,string>` in a `List` with three given items, but it doesn't matter what the fourth is. Ex:

```
Listoftuples.IndexOf(new Tuple<string,string,string,string>("value1","value2","value3","this value does not matter"))
```

Is there a wild card characters when it comes to indexes, or is there a different way to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int index = Listoftuples.FindIndex(t => t.Item1 == "value1" && t.Item2 == "value2" && t.Item3 == "value3");
```

You might want to create a function to create the predicate:

```
Func<Tuple<string,string,string,string>, bool> CreateMatcher(string first, string second, string third)
{
    return t => t.Item1 == first && t.Item2 == second && t.Item3 == third;
}
```

then you can use

```
int index = Listoftuples.FindIndex(CreateMatcher("value1", "value2", "value3"));
```

Comment: @flq - Thanks, I was looking for that but missed it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that complex.  Here's a general purpose helper method:

```
public static int IndexOf<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TKey key
    , Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (object.Equals(selector(item), key))
            return i;
        i++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Now that you have an `IndexOf` method that takes a selector, it's as simple as:

```
list.IndexOf(Tuple.Create("value1", "value2", "value3")
    , item => Tuple.Create(item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3));
```

Note that you could add an `IComparer<TKey>` as an optional parameter to the `IndexOf` method if you wanted to make it more general purpose.

Answer (score 1):

While Oded's answer is (was) correct, Linq has a built-in way to do just about everything list-based, so you don't have to roll your own.

```
var myElement = (Listoftuples.Select((x,i)=>new {Index = i, 
                          Element = Tuple.Create(x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Item3})
                      .FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Element == TupleToSearchFor);
var myIndex = myElement == null ? -1 : myElement.Index;
```

Breaking it down:

- There is an overload of the Select() method that accepts a lambda with two parameters; the current element of the source enumerable *and* the "index" of that element in the source (understand that this only works for us because we're not changing the order of any elements in the original list; if we sorted it first, the indexes wouldn't match between Listoftuples and the elements passed into Select().

  We then use this method to produce elements of an anonymous type, which does two things for us; first, we can change the Tuple to a Tuple of three values (the first three of each source Tuple, which are the ones we care about), and second, we can relatively easily "bolt on" the index of the element in the original list for later reference.
- FirstOrDefault() spins through the results of the Select() call until it finds an element where the Tuple matches the one we are searching for (or it doesn't find anything, in which case it returns null).
- Because FirstOrDefault() could return null, we need to check for it. There are many ways to do that; the one I put in, with the ternary statement, is simple and understandable enough.

At the end, myIndex will have the index of the first matching element of Listoftuples, or -1, which means none of the elements of Listoftuples match the one you searched for.